# Shell - How to find a word at a certain point in a message

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to change my command:

```
anzahl=`cat $1 | grep -i "error" | wc -l`
```

This command also counts messages which are like this:

```
2017-07-15 03:07:02,746 [INFO] blabla:123 @blabla:123 - rhsmd started. Error.
```

But there is the word Info. So I dont want that it counts.
I just want messages like this:

```
2017-07-15 06:12:45,362 [ERROR] blabla:123    @blabla:123- Either the consumer is not registered or the  certificates are corrupted. Certificate update using daemon failed.
```

Some tips how I can do this?

Comment: The only way is to make your regular expression tighter (e.g. change `error` to `\[ERROR\]` but that can flake out too at which time, you'll probably need to move to a parseable log format.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want:

```
anzahl=$(grep -c '\[ERROR\]' "$1")
```

This would search for the literal string `[ERROR]` in the logfile, `-c` returns the number of matches which makes `wc -l` superfluous.

Anyhow this would still match `[ERROR]` at any position of the strings. While this should be good enough in most cases, more precise would be this awk command:

```
anzahl=$(awk '$3=="[ERROR]"{c++}END{print c}' "$1")
```

This command would check if `[ERROR]` appears exactly in the third column of a line and counts those lines. At the end of input it prints the count.

---

Btw, German variable names doesn't suit for an international audience as on Stackoverflow. I recommend to use English variable names: *count*

Comment: Nice alternate to account for the string showing up in the wrong place. I suggested a grotty regex, but awk is a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually want a regular expression but really just want to count a string, there are grep options for that:

```
   -c, --count
          Suppress  normal output; instead print a count of matching lines
          for each input file.

   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret  PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by new-
          lines, any of which is to be matched.
```

So your command should be:

```
anzahl=$(grep -c -F '[ERROR]' "$1")
```

Of course, even that string might appear some place other than the third whitespace-delimited field of the line. If you want to stick with grep rather than switching to a tool like awk for your counting, you can do so by going back to what is perhaps an awkward regular expression:

```
anzahl=$(grep -c -E '^[^ ]+ [^ ]+ [[]ERROR[]]' "$1")
```

This uses grep's `-E` option to specify that you're using an Extended regular expression. The expression consists of two strings of not-space, each followed by a space, all of which is followed by your error tag.